# Login destination error

Tags: views, 7

I have installed [Login Destination](http://drupal.org/project/login_destination) and set the redirect URL as node/5.
Then I got the following message. Can anyone let me know what is this about? the functionality is also not working.

```
Your settings: (double-check them)
[ld_url_type] => 'static'
[ld_url_destination] => 'user'
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but your phrasing of the question doesn't make sense to me. Please try to improve it.